# Salt-Stack mysql_grants.present Underscore Wildcard

Tags: mysql, salt-stack

I'm using Salt to provision cloud servers but I'm having problems with MySQLdb producing the correct permissions for MySQL. If I was executing the SQL directly it would be:

```
GRANT ALL ON `install\_%`.* TO 'installer'@'localhost';
```

The sls file contains:

```
installer_local_install_grants:
  mysql_grants.present:
    - grant: all privileges
    - database: install\_%.*
    - user: installer
    - host: localhost
    - escape: False
```

Which produces this error:

```
    Function: mysql_grants.present
  Result: False
 Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 1560, in call
              **cdata['kwargs'])
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/mysql_grants.py", line 187, in present
              grant, database, user, host, grant_option, escape, ssl_option, **connection_args
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/mysql.py", line 1666, in grant_add
              _execute(cur, qry['qry'], qry['args'])
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/mysql.py", line 505, in _execute
              return cur.execute(qry, args)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
              query = query % db.literal(args)
          TypeError: * wants int
```

With debug in salt turned on the relevant line prior to submitting to MySQLdb is:

```
Doing query: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON install\_%.* TO %(user)s@%(host)s args: {'host': 'localhost', 'user': 'installer'}
```

So it seems Salt is outputting the correct code but MySQLdb is not handling some part of the query correctly. The query is missing the back ticks but I'm really not sure how to get those in.

With the escape removed or set to True the grants look like:

```
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Host      | Db              | User             |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| localhost | install\\_\%    | installer        |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

When it should look like:

```
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Host      | Db              | User             |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| localhost | install\_%      | installer        |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried putting single quotes around `install\_%.*`?

Comment: Yes I have tried `'install\_%.*'` and double quotes with back ticks around the DB name

Answer (score 0):

OK, would you open an issue referencing this SO post?  Thanks!

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/new

Comment: Ok, so it might not just be me. I'll open the issue in a little bit. Thanks